# How can I add empty rows in SQL SERVER for this example?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, days

[Sql Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/155a2/2)

I have this table structure:

```
    CREATE TABLE Schedule
    ([Day] varchar(13), [Starts] varchar(57), [Ends] varchar(57))
;

INSERT INTO Schedule
    ([Day], [Starts], [Ends])
VALUES
    ('2', '09:00', '15:00'),
   ('5', '10:00', '12:00'),
  ('3', '09:00', '18:00')
;
```

And this simple query to show the current rows:

```
   SELECT
 DATENAME(weekday,  Day - 1) as days,
  Starts,
  Ends  
FROM
  Schedule
  order by Day
```

The last query get this result:

```
Day        Starts    Ends
---        -------   ----
Tuesday    09:00     15:00
Wednesday  09:00     18:00
Friday     10:00     12:00
```

I want to fill the table with the days that doesn't appear in the registers

This is the final result I want to get:

```
    Day        Starts    Ends
    ---        -------   ----
    Monday     NULL      NULL
    Tuesday    09:00     15:00
    Wednesday  09:00     18:00
    Thursday   NULL      NULL
    Friday     10:00     12:00
```

How can I get this?, thanks

Comment: this might work for a single week, but what if there is more than 1 week?

Comment: In this case I have always this structure for schedule, so I don't have to worry about more than one week

Comment: What does `day` represent? The actual week day? Like @Tanner said what if there's more than one week? I would make a table called "weekdays" and put your days in there then do a left join to your Schedule table. Left join will add NULL rows if there are empty days in Schedule. But that still doesn't help your (apparent) issue of using the table ID as the day of the week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, create a reference table for days then Right Join to your select query.

```
            SELECT  DATENAME(WEEKDAY, TBL.days - 1) AS days ,
                    starts ,
                    ends
            FROM    ( SELECT    Day days ,
                                Starts ,
                                Ends
                      FROM      Schedule
                    ) T
                    RIGHT JOIN ( SELECT [days]
                                 FROM   ( SELECT    1 [days]
                                          UNION 
                                          SELECT    2
                                          UNION 
                                          SELECT    3
                                          UNION 
                                          SELECT    4
                                          UNION 
                                          SELECT    5
                                          UNION 
                                          SELECT    6
                                          UNION 
                                          SELECT    7
                                        ) S
                               ) TBL ON TBL.days = t.days
```

Results:

```
        days         starts    ends
        ------------ --------- ------------
        Monday       NULL      NULL
        Tuesday      09:00     15:00
        Wednesday    09:00     18:00
        Thursday     NULL      NULL
        Friday       10:00     12:00
        Saturday     NULL      NULL
        Sunday       NULL      NULL

        (7 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Your answer works perfect for that I need, thanks :-)

Answer (score 3):

I would create an empy base table and do a LEFT JOIN:

```
CREATE TABLE Schedule
(Day VARCHAR(13), Starts VARCHAR(57), Ends   VARCHAR(57));

INSERT INTO Schedule (Day, Starts,Ends)

VALUES
('2', '09:00','15:00'),
('5', '10:00','12:00'),
('3', '09:00','18:00');


CREATE TABLE ScheduleBase
(Day    VARCHAR(13), Starts VARCHAR(57), Ends VARCHAR(57));


INSERT INTO ScheduleBase
(Day, Starts, Ends)
VALUES
('1', NULL, NULL),
('2', NULL, NULL),
('3', NULL, NULL),
('4', NULL, NULL),
('5', NULL, NULL)

SELECT SB.Day, S.Starts, S.Ends FROM ScheduleBase AS SB LEFT JOIN Schedule 
AS S ON SB.Day = S.Day
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this if you do not want to create new table

```
select
    DATENAME(weekday,  Day - 1) as days, max(Starts), max(Ends)
from (
    SELECT
        Day, Starts, Ends  
    FROM
        Schedule
    union all 
    select 
        *, null, null 
    from (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7)) t(d)
) t
group by Day
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a common table expressin to generate a week calendar "table" on the fly:

```
with range (num) as (
  select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3
  union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6
  union all select 7
 )
SELECT
 DATENAME(weekday,  range.num - 1),
  Starts,
  Ends  
FROM
  Schedule
  right outer join range on range.num = Schedule.day
  order by range.num
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/26252/8/0)